# Getting information from one table and saving the returned information in new table - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm making a school system for my school and I have this problem in which I'm stuck for days. In my app I have users with type `admin`, `teacher` and `student`. The admin creates all the users and all the other information. Now I'm making the teacher panel in which the teacher will be able to add marks for the students and later they will be displayed in the student panel.

So in first place when the teachers get into their account he will be able to pick a class which he teaches and the subjects which he teaches, for that case I have table - `class_subjects` in which I'm saving the `teacher_id`, `subject_id` and `class_id` from the admin panel. I'm calling this here, in my teacher panel, and it seems to work just fine, because I see the exact classes and subjects I need. After that I need to make a post query with these both picked from the teacher and in return to get all the students from the picked class + the picked subject, that also works exactly how I want it. So what I am returning is a new blade with arrays with information from the table `class_subject`, from this returned arrays the teacher need to pick information, and here in text field he must add his mark for the student he picks. After that I need to save the picked information in new table called `student_marks` with fields `student_id`, `subject_id`, `mark_type_id`, `mark`.

My question is how the save this information (that the teacher picks) in the new table (`student_marks`)?

I'm posting the controller:

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex() {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $classStudent = ClassSubject::where('teacher_id','=',$user->id)->get()->lists('class_id');
        $userSubject = ClassSubject::where('teacher_id','=',$user->id)->get()->lists('subject_id');

        return view('educator.account.account',[
            'user' => $user,
            'userTeacher'=> $classStudent,
            'userSubject'=> $userSubject,
        ]);
    }

    public function postIndex(Request $request) {
       ClassSubject::where(
            'subject_id','=',$request->get('userSubject'),
            'class_id','=',$request->get('userClass')
        );

        $user = Auth::user();
        $markType = MarkType::lists('type');
        $sub = Subject::where('id','=',$request->get('userSubject'))->get()->lists('name');
        $stu =  User::where('class_id','=',$request->get('userClass'))
            ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->get()->lists('full_name');

        return view('educator.account.input', [
            'user' => $user,
            'studentss'=> $stu,
            'markType' => $markType ,
            'sub'=> $sub,

    }
```

I know its a bit twisted but I'm really stuck in here and I will be really grateful if someone can finally help me with this. If something is unclear, please ask.

educator.account.account (first blade)

```
@extends('teacher-app')
@section('teacher-content')
    <div class="col-md-6">
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('profile_id','Избери клас:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-4']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::select('userClass', $userTeacher, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('profile_id','Избери предмет:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-4']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::select('userSubject', $userSubject, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div align="center">

            {!! Form::submit('Избери', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}



            @stop
    </div>
```

educator.account.input (second blade)

```
@extends('teacher-app')
@section('teacher-content')
    <div class="col-md-8">



        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('profile_id','Ученик:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-4']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::select('userStu', $studentss, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            {!! Form::label('profile_id','Оценка:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-4']) !!}

            <div class="col-md-2">
                {!! Form::text('mark',null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('profile_id','Тип оценка:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-4']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::select('markType', $markType, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('profile_id','Предмет:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-4']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::select('stuSub', $sub, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

        </div>

        <br>


        <div align="center">
            <a href="{{url('educator/account')}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Назад</button></a>
            {!! Form::submit('Запиши', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}

        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}


        </div>


        @stop
```

Comment: Why not just create an html form specific to these updates? The first question is: how are you submitting this data to the server? Ajax? If it's just a standard post, submit the form to the proper route with a data structure that matches your table and you can almost directly insert (on duplicate update) the entry. Then redirect back and load the new data. Does that make sense?

Comment: do you have a model for Student marks? or how do you define the relations?

Comment: Yes, I have model for every table. @Emn1ty I am not using Ajax, a standard post, but I don't know how to do that that you are telling me... It's my first Laravel project and I'm new.

Comment: I can post both blades if it will help...

Comment: It would be helpful to at least see the form structure, yes.

Comment: Okay i will update in a min, checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they submit the form for the student rating, you'll have a route similar to this to post to:

```
class AccountController extends Controller {

    public function markStudent(Request $request)
    {
        // get request data
        $mark = $request->input('mark');
        $subject_id = $request->input('stuSub');
        $mark_type = $request->input('markType');
        $student_id = $request->input('userStu');

        // get the existing record or create a new, empty record
        $student_mark = StudentMark::firstOrNew(compact('student_id', 'subject_id'));

        // add the updated data to the model
        $student_mark->fill(compact('mark_type', 'mark'));

        // persist to database
        $student_mark->save();

        // redirect or do whatever you want after request completion...
    }
}
```

This above code assumes you only want one entry per student, per subject (ie. a unique index on both these columns).

I would also recommend that you validate the data before inserting it, either by doing so before the `StudentMark::firstOrNew()` or by [creating a custom request object with validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation).

Comment: I'm getting unused local variable for the fist $mark

Comment: Updated, should be corrected though you may need to modify this code to match your own since I do not have the ability to test it.

Comment: Yes. But when submit it looks like the submit button listens to the previous `postIndex` method and messes all my data...

Comment: You will have to set the post route manually, it defaults to the current page. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html <- documentation

Comment: How can I do that? Here my routes:

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']
           ], function () {
               Route::group([
                   'prefix' => 'educator',
                  'namespace' => 'Educator'
             ], function () {
                   Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');

              });

           });`

Comment: `Form::open(['action' => 'AccountController@markStudent'])` and in your routes: `Route::post('account/student/mark', 'AccountController@markStudent')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104484/discussion-between-yoanna-murdjeva-and-emn1ty).